# Inverse a sparse matrix with reduced bandwidth: faster or not

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, matrix-inverse

I have an adjacency matrix of size `1393 x 1393`, which looks like:
[image]

I am doing spatial modeling based on this matrix and later on there will be intensive matrix inverse involved. I heard for a sparse matrix like this, we can reorder the rows and columns to achieve minimum bandwidth, which will greatly reduce the time needed for matrix inverse. The algorithm I found is called Gibbs-Poole-Stockmeyer, and I found a FORTRAN [implementation](http://www.netlib.org/toms-2014-06-10/582)

I am an R user and currently working on calling this old FORTRAN code in R but with no success (still trying). So my questions are:

1. Is it true that when using R/Rcpparmadillo, the matrix inverse for a sparse matrix will be easier if I reduce the bandwidth? Do I need any explicit command to tell R how to inverse the matrix or it's just happenning naturally.
2. Can anyone help me use the FORTRAN code in R? I'm still trying and will upload the errors on my side.

Thanks!

Edit:
I found another algorithm: Cuthill–McKee algorithm for the same purpose. This problem falls under graph theory field.
With the help of R package: `RBGL`, I managed to reordering the rows and columns of the original matrix by renaming the vertices in the graph, and have the new structure:
[image]
However, When I tested the computation time for matrix inverse, there is no difference: `Bmat` is the old matrix while `new_B` is the one with reduced bandwidth.

```
n = dim(Bmat)[1]
IrhoC = diag(n) - 0.1 * Bmat
IrhoC2 = diag(n) - 0.1 * new_B
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  old = chol2inv(chol(IrhoC)),
  new = chol2inv(chol(IrhoC2)),
  solve_old = chol2inv(chol(IrhoC)),
  solve_new = chol2inv(chol(IrhoC2)),
  times = 10
)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval cld
       old 59.66203 65.81924 106.55729 82.68835 94.74017 346.38852    10   a
       new 68.26124 76.63195  82.13040 81.81659 87.03293  97.39588    10   a
 solve_old 65.39816 79.67434  82.78533 85.27720 89.92952  94.98980    10   a
 solve_new 60.42481 64.97768  77.97695 77.98818 87.53069  99.21062    10   a
```

It turned out there is no time difference for those matrix inverse. At this point, I don't know what kind of commands/options are needed to take advantage of the new reduced bandwidth matrix.

Comment: You may have better luck asking about the numerical mathematics aspects of this question at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Perhaps someone can help you, but that is not a question you should ask here. Should I just answer "yes" or "no"? Show us what you have and we can have a look. If I were you I would ask here about the call of that Fortran code from R here and the about the math at scicomp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for your comments. I realized my questions are bad as well so I modified it. Also, I think I have achieved my purpose but gain no benefits from that. I may post a new question under the link you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will still be helpful.

Probably you didn't find difference because the Cholesky method invoked is a standard one, i.e. is not designed for sparse (reordered) matrices. I've found a method that seems to work in the scikit.sparse library (Python). 
However, your problem is very similar to the example showed in: Rue and Held,2005 , "Gaussian Markov Random Fields (GMRF) / Theory and applications" (section 2.5.). They released an R package for GMRFs called: GMRFLib that hopefully will do what you needed for.